# What is the correct way to solve a linking error?

Tags: cmake, makefile

I'm using cmake on Ubuntu 14.04 to build [pdf2htmlEx](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX).

It required building poppler version >= 0.25. I built poppler version 0.35.0.

After this I was getting a linking error due to the earlier version of poppler getting linked.

I fixed this by doing this:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libpoppler.so.54.0.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so
```

Basically pointing the poppler version here to the newly built version. This seemed like a hack.

My question is if I have two version of the same library, how do I make sure that "cmake" and "make" and "g++" (cmake was configured for poppler >= 0.25.0) finds the correct version? How do you correctly debug and fix such a linking error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way would be to modify some variable (`POPPLER_LIBRARY`, i guess) in `builddir/CMakeCache.txt`. Be sure to regenerate build files with `cmake .` after editing this file (actually, in case of "unix makefiles" generator, running `make` will do too).

You can also use `cmake-gui` app, which allows you to view and edit cache values with nice graphical interface.

Comment: A point I need to make, I did regenerate the file with "cmake ." multiple times.